Young's two-slites experiment for macroscopic objects in an opaque unsonarized environment
I was wondering what would happen if such experiment is realized using millions of sand particles for example, and adapted dimensions of the slits that makes it possible for the sand particles to go through them.
I especially want to know if such experiment was already done?

Why sand? And why millions of grains? Large (C60) molecules have been successfully shown to produce interference effects in a double slit setup, but a grain of sand is not going to produce a noticeable quantum effect.

Thank you very much for you answer. I know about the C60 molecule experiment, and that it has shown interference. However this molecule is not considered macroscopic particle, it is still considered somehow quantum.
Sand grains was just an example, but what I want to know is was this experiment conducted with undoubtedly macroscopic elements? and especially in a totally disconnected environment from an observer?
(and i said millions but i mean just enough for the experiment)

No answers? anybody can give some info please?

no not for macro objects ... it does not make sense.  In general the EM field is responsible for all interactions of matter ... the particle is dumb .... the EM field of the particle .... interacts with the EM field of the apparatus ... for small objects the wave properties become evident.

There are experiments already that demonstrate that the observer is not necessary in the double slit equation. As to macroscopic versus microscopic: As the particles get bigger, the which path information is available regardless of whether there is an observer to see it. As a result, there is no interference on the larger particles. So there really is nothing much to look at, which is why there are no experiments.

There are a couple of reasons why such an experiment would be difficult. The first is related to the deBroglie wavelength of a particle that we would want to measure:
$$
\lambda =\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2mk_BT}}
$$
where $m$ is the mass of the particle, $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant, $T$ is the temperature and $\hbar$ is Planck's constant. Interference experiments have been successfully performed with molecules like Buckyballs that contain 60 carbon atoms so it has a mass of about 720 protons: $1.2\times 10^{-24}kg$ so it has a wavelength of the order of $10^{-10}m$ at 1K. A grain of sand has a mass of about $10^{-5}kg$ so its wavelength is of the order of $10^{-20}m$, which is a lot smaller and is technologically infeasible to measure.
There is an additional problem. When information is copied out of a quantum system interference is suppressed: an effect called decoherence. In a standard model of decoherence the time after which interference is suppresssed, the decoherence time, is proportional to the square of the deBroglie wavelength
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
So decoherence happens about $10^{20}$ times faster for a grain of sand than for a molecule, which is technologically infeasible to measure. In addition, neither a molecule nor a grain of sand is just a particle so they have internal vibrational modes that can get in the way of interference experiments.
For a longer review of decoherence, including accounts of some experiments with molecules in Section 6.2, see:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
